# Changing a block title per theme or page

Tags: 7, views, blocks

I have a search view, and I use the exposed form as a block to put the search box on every page.  In the block configuration I hide the exposed form block title so that I'll just get the search form with no title.

That works fine, but now on the Admin dashboard, I want to include the same search box.  The dashboard shows the block title, which is what I want, except the view title is 'Exposed form: publication_search-page' which is gross.

If I try to go into the block configuration and change the block title to Publication Search, I override the  that is in there now, and the title starts showing up everywhere.

How can I change the block title in the dashboard (or when I'm using the adminimal theme or whatever the admin theme is set to if that is easier) without messing up the configuration to hide it on all the other pages?

Comment: Have you set the title within the views view display for the block?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that I know what you mean, but since I didn't bother setting a display name, it is set to page.  I want the block title to end up being Publication Search.

Answer (score 1):

#### Here is a per theme solution.

In your View, under Advanced, click on `Theme Information`, the following pops up:

[image]

Now click on `style output`, and copy the entire code inside in to a new file in your text/code editor.

In my case it is:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Default simple view template to display a list of rows.
 *
 * @ingroup views_templates
 */
?>
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Change the `<h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>` to `<h3>Your Custom Title</h3>`

Then save the file as **views-view-unformated--[view-name]--[[machine-name]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsMjX.jpg).tpl.php**

(In my screenshot, `example` is the name of my view, and machine name is `page`, **basically use last name suggestion**)

[image]

Put this template file in your Adminimal theme's template folder and clear the cache to see changes.

Comment: Thanks, that is great, I'll try to see if I can modify that to remove the title from my non admin theme while allowing me to configure it elsewhere.

Comment: It wasn't working for me so I turned on theme debug, and see that the template names are different for exposed forms.  I'm getting block--views---exp-publication-search-page.tpl.php.  Now I need to go find that default exposed form template.

Comment: @UltraBob Click on `Theme Information` link in views.

Comment: Yeah, I did that.  It doesn't give me any information on exposed form views.

Comment: So I've tried copying views-exposed-form.tpl.php from views to block--views---exp-publication-search-page.tpl.php in my theme, but even when I don't change anything I get warnings that $widgets is undefined, so I seem to be on the wrong track there.  Following the guidance in the answer had no impact on how the exposed form block appeared.  My first thought was to do a preprocess_block theme function, but I didn't have much success with that at first, maybe I should try at that some more.

Comment: @UltraBob sorry I was busy with a client. I gtg to bed now, I'll look at this again tomorrow.

Comment: The solution that works so far is to hide the title using css from the non-admin theme.  I'd still like to understand more about how to do this kind of theming override though, so I'd love an answer about how to stop it being output at all.